# GRUB can't boot on Arch after Windows install

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, grub

I have grub installed on `/dev/sdb1`
I have swap on `/dev/sdb2`
I have archlinux / on `/dev/sdb3`
I have windows on `/dev/sdb4`

When I didn't install windows, the system booted on grub, and then it booted on arch.

Now I've installed windows; first, I couldn't boot on grub at all.

Then, I've `chrooted` and `grub-install`, `grub-mkconfig`, etc..
I've set the `/dev/sdb1` to bootable.

Now, it boot to `/dev/sdb1`, but it show only Windows entry, and when I `chroot` into arch, I do `os-prober`, `genfstab`, etc, it don't want to work... It only show me windows on `/dev/sdb4`.

Comment: See this article (Dual Boot paragraph): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Bootloader_installation

Comment: Remember You should install windows first and linux second.Windows didnt have grub bootloader.

Comment: So, should i reinstall my linux OS next to windows, with Windows already installed ? And, it's good to modifiy entry into the bootloader ? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Multiple_entries

Comment: Maybe i founded :D ! I need to test and i will inform you in this post tomorrow. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Dual-booting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution !
I don't know if it's the cleanest, but it worked.

**I modified grub.cfg** with a LiveUSB Linux, and **i manually added an entry to the GRUB Menu** :D !

Now **it works like if the OS Prober detected Arch Linux**, but i added it manually.

Thanks to the helpers !